# resource mapping not found for name: "myname-myname" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, sonarqube, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to migrate the K8S api extensions/v1beta1 to networking.k8s.io/v1
[Deprecated API Migration Guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122)

helm\templates\ingress.yaml (before migration)

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $serviceName := include "sonarqube.fullname" . -}}
{{- $servicePort := .Values.service.externalPort -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "sonarqube.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "sonarqube.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
{{- if .Values.ingress.labels }}
{{ .Values.ingress.labels | toYaml | trimSuffix "\n"| indent 4 -}}
{{- end}}
{{- if .Values.ingress.annotations}}
  annotations:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.ingress.annotations }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    {{- $path := default "/" .path }}
    - host: {{ .name }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: {{ $path }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $serviceName }}
              servicePort: {{ $servicePort }}
          - path: {{ printf "%s/*" (trimSuffix "/" $path) }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $serviceName }}
              servicePort: {{ $servicePort }}
```

helm\templates\ingress.yaml (after migration)

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $serviceName := include "sonarqube.fullname" . -}}
{{- $servicePort := .Values.service.externalPort -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "sonarqube.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "sonarqube.name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
{{- if .Values.ingress.labels }}
{{ .Values.ingress.labels | toYaml | trimSuffix "\n"| indent 4 -}}
{{- end}}
{{- if .Values.ingress.annotations}}
  annotations:
    {{- range $key, $value := .Values.ingress.annotations }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $value | quote }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
spec:
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    {{- $path := default "/" .path }}
    - host: {{ .name }}
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: {{ $serviceName }}
                port:
                  number: {{ $servicePort }}
            path: {{ $path }}
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          - backend:
              service:
                name: {{ $serviceName }}
                port:
                  number: {{ $servicePort }}
            path: {{ printf "%s/*" (trimSuffix "/" $path) }}
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    {{- end -}}
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
{{ toYaml .Values.ingress.tls | indent 4 }}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

And after migration getting into below error:
(in my helm feature branch there is nowhere mention extensions/v1beta1)

`Error: UPGRADE FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from  current release manifest: resource mapping not found for name: "myname-myname" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1" ensure CRDs are installed first`

My K8S ingress is already running on networking.k8s.io/v1
`

```
abhi@mySystem:$ kubectl get ing myname-myname -n sonarqube -o yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: sonarqube
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: sonarqube
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 200m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: 200m
  creationTimestamp: "2021-11-16T14:34:25Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: sonarqube
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: sonarqube-3.10.5
    heritage: Helm
    release: sonarqube
  name: myname-myname
  namespace: sonarqube
  resourceVersion: "111111111"
  uid: 11a1a11a-1111-11aa-a11a-aa1a111aa111
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sonarqube-dev.ad.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myname-myname
            port:
              number: 9000
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myname-myname
            port:
              number: 9000
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.110.110.110
```

Helm Version 3.5.1 | Kubectl Client Version: v1.25.3 | Kubectl Server Version: v1.23.5

I trying to Migrate Kubernetes api extensions/v1beta1 to networking.k8s.io/v1

Comment: are you able to see `networking.k8s.io/v1` when you run ` kubectl api-versions | grep -i network`?

Comment: @Adiii Yes, able to see networking.k8s.io/v1

Comment: did you try to delete and recreate?